# How to Lookup from Different Dataframe into a Middle Column of First Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have 2 DataFrames from 2 different csv file and both file have let's say 5 columns each. And I need to lookup 1 column from the second DataFrame into the first DataFrame so the first DataFrame will has 6 columns and lookup using the ID.

Example are as below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[6661, 'Lily', 21, 5000, 'USA'], [6672, 'Mark', 32, 32500, 'Canada'], [6631, 'Rose', 20, 1500, 'London'], 
    [6600, 'Jenifer', 42, 50000, 'London'], [6643, 'Sue', 27, 8000, 'Turkey']]
ds_main = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Income', 'Country'])

data2 = [[6672, 'Mark', 'Shirt', 8.5, 2], [6643, 'Sue', 'Scraft', 2.0, 5], [6661, 'Lily', 'Blouse', 11.9, 2], 
        [6600, 'Jenifer', 'Shirt', 9.8, 1], [6631, 'Rose', 'Pants', 4.5, 2]]
ds_rate = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Product', 'Rate', 'Quantity'])
```

[image]

[image]

I wanted to lookup the 'Rate' from `ds_rate` into the `ds_main`. However, I wanted the rate to be place in the middle of the `ds_main` DataFrame.

The result should be as below:

[image]

I have tried using merge and insert, still unable to get the result that I wanted. Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `set_index` + `loc` to get "Rate" sorted according to its "ID" in `ds_main`; then `insert`:

```
ds_main.insert(3, 'Rate', ds_rate.set_index('ID')['Rate'].loc[ds_main['ID']].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
     ID     Name  Age  Rate  Income Country
0  6661     Lily   21  11.9    5000     USA
1  6672     Mark   32   8.5   32500  Canada
2  6631     Rose   20   4.5    1500  London
3  6600  Jenifer   42   9.8   50000  London
4  6643      Sue   27   2.0    8000  Turkey
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `'ID'` is unique

```
ds_main.iloc[:, :3].merge(ds_rate[['ID', 'Rate']]).join(ds_main.iloc[:, 3:])

     ID     Name  Age  Rate  Income Country
0  6661     Lily   21  11.9    5000     USA
1  6672     Mark   32   8.5   32500  Canada
2  6631     Rose   20   4.5    1500  London
3  6600  Jenifer   42   9.8   50000  London
4  6643      Sue   27   2.0    8000  Turkey
```